# How to determine if case owner is queue with specific developer name

Tags: apex, queue

I have a problem with selecting specific custom queue in apex code.

For example I have:

```
        Case c = (Case) controller.getRecord();
        String queueName = c.Owner.Name;

        if (queueName != 'ATM_queue') { 
           //DO SOMETHING
        }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no direct relationship between Owner and DeveloperName, because it is a [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object. If you really want to check by developer name, you'll have to query for it:

```
if(c.ownerid.getsobjecttype() == Group.SobjectType) {
  Group queue = [select developername from group where id = :c.ownerid];
  if(Queue.DeveloperName == 'atm_queue') {
```

As an alternative, you could also create a formula field to return the value, something like `owner:queue.developername`, and then you can check that value instead.

Comment: +1 for formula field as it saves queries, Downside(Only 20 object references on a case and that can be bit tricky)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you specifically need Developer Name or if you can use friendly name instead, but the Owner.Name field **is** populated when the Owner is a queue - but it uses the display name. So if your queue is called "ATM Queue" then the Owner.Name will be ATM Queue and your if statement would be:

```
if(queueName != 'ATM Queue'){
    // Do Something
}
```

Additionally, to make sure that the owner IS a queue before you assign the queueName string, you should do a Owner Check to see if the Owner is a User or a queue, like this:

```
String queueName;
String ownerId;
Case c = (Case) controller.getRecord();
ownerId = c.OwnerId;
if(String.valueOf(ownerId).startsWith('00G')){
    queueName = c.Owner.Name;
}

if (queueName != 'ATM Queue') { 
   //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: `if(c.OwnerId.getSobjectType() == Group.SobjectType)` is more self-documenting instead of relying on the key prefix.

Comment: I actually didn't even know that you could use .getSObjectType() in that context, that's very good information, thanks!